# how to solve the redirect url loop error in wp config wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, http-redirect

my website is on wordpress, i want to redirect my webiste from **icap.org.pk** to **www.icap.org.pk** , but when i changed in wp.config file its show me error "The page isn't redirecting properly".

here is my code please suggest me how to do that:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^icap.org.pk$" />
      </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.icap.org.pk/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
<match url="*"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714732/web-config-redirect-non-www-to-www) your web.config is fine the problem is most likely with your database table for wordpress options..solution: login to database and be sure the set the url with www and not without www.

Comment: yes thnx problem is solved now, i just delete the .htaccess file and my update the URL in wp-option table with "www". also my hosting provider make changes in webconfig file.