# Forcefully open site to www only .

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web

I had hosted site in `IIS` which open in `url` like `http://www.example.com` as well as `http://example.com`
but i dont want to open it in `http://example.com` ,
 `http://example.com` might change to `http://www.example.com` Forcefully, what confugeration shoud i wright in `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

**(Note: Updated answer below)**

This requires you to make use of URL-rewriting.

This post here shows how to make use of the URL-Rewriting extensions:

http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/08/iis-7-redirect-domaincom-to.html

If you don't see this extension via IIS manager, you can download the extension here:
http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

You will want to add a rule, look under "search engine optimization" and edit "canonical domain name".

There you can direct all traffic to the www-version of the domain by selecting it in the dropdown.

**EDIT:**
As for the question to do it in **web.config**, this is an example configuration:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" 
        url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
      <add key="on" value="https" />
      <add key="off" value="http" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Hope that helps,

Sebastian

Comment: is there any way to configure by writting some thing in web.config

Comment: Please see this related question, i think the answer can be applied in your case as well:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714732/web-config-redirect-non-www-to-www)