# URLRewrite to add www for http and https

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I need url-rewrite (or any other method) do the following:

```
http://domain.com > http://www.domain.com
https://domain.com > https://www.domain.com
```

I've seen a lot of posts to redirect to www and a lot to force https but none of them that does both.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should help:

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually found another answer on SO as well (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17715586/2412080). Still need to implement so will try both of these.

Answer (score 0):

this rule i use is applying WWW for both http and https (just copy and paste) :

```
<rule name="ensure www" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://(?!www)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

hope this helps.