# Want to Open My Website with www

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, url-rewriting

I have any asp.net mvc website, and I want to open it as `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`. I want to redirect every user who uses `example.com` to `www.example.com`. The reason why I am doing this is to maintain the cookies. As currently 2 different cookies sets one works for `www.example.com` and the other works for `example.com`. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you need to look into .htaccess redirects

Comment: Why don't you just set the cookie for `.example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for that. But it is not installed on the server by default. When installed you can create a rule in the `Web.Config` file of your site.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^traindb.nl" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.traindb.nl/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done in web.config, not .htaccess. There's a similar question with a great response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17715586/7509168).

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the redirection from example.com -> www.example.com at the DNS or even in IIS settings.