# Web.config rewrite http + www and http non www and https non-www to to https://www

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have recently switched my asp.net MVC website to https and want all existing traffic to get redirected to https://www.example.com using web.config rewrite.

I have tried various combinations but not yet successful.

need to handle following three scenarios :

```
 
http://
http://www
https://
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714732/web-config-redirect-non-www-to-www/17715586#17715586 might help

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="(.*)" /> 
        <conditions> 
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions> 
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" 
             url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>   
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen  but this doesn't take care of www  I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your traffic to use the https using the `Global.asax` as well.

Method name:  `Application_BeginRequest`

Your code to redirect will look something like this

```
strProtocol = "https";

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("http:") == true)
{
    Response.Redirect(strProtocol + "://" + strYourHostName + strYourRemainingURL, false);
}
```

you can keep the protocol and hostname in the web.config and pick from there.